# Internet Explorer 11 remove frequent sites history

Tags: history, internet-explorer-11

When I open a new tab in IE 11, a new tab page opens just fine but I also get a popup box showing the last 10 addresses.
I try to clear log, no change.
I try private browsing, no change.
I try clean all With CCleaner, no change.

The last 10 adresses entered shows up in a popup box in the middle of the screen. How can I close/get rid of this?

Comment: Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/946442/edit) your question to make the title summarize your question. *"I have a Win 7 IE 11 laptop"* is really, really a bad title. Success!

Comment: What do you mean by popup box? Do you mean the ten square boxes under the 'Frequent' title? If you want a completely blank tab you can go to Internet Options -> Tabs and change the 'When a new tab is opened, open:' dropdown box to 'A blank page'

Comment: In addition, you can remove individual sites from the Frequent list by clicking the little X in the upper, right corner of the individual squares.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the squares in the middle of the new tab page? Those are your **Frequent** sites.

If you don't want them to be displayed, simply click **Hide sites** in the bottom right corner.